# How to infer the data type from the unserializer function return type in a React / Remix hook?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, remix.run

We're building a pretty basic CRUD application with Remix. Our routes re-use loader data from their parent routes, so I created a custom hook, `useTypedRouteLoaderData`, which is pretty much equivalent to `useLoaderData` and `useRouteLoaderData`. The loader data also has to be unserialized before consumption.

This was my initial attempt. Worked, but quite verbose and ugly. Having to manually define the unserializer function in 20 something routes? Yeah, no.

```
const data = useTypedRouteLoaderData<typeof otherLoader>('routes/stuff');
const unserializer = (x: typeof data) => {
  const { stuff, popular: _unusedHere, ...rest } = x;

  return {
    ...rest,
    stuff: stuff.map((x) => unserialize<Stuff>(x)),
  };
};
const [stableData, update] = useState(unserializer(data));

useEffect(() => {
  if (data) {
    update(unserializer(data));
  }
}, [data]);

export function useTypedRouteLoaderData<T = any>(
  routeId: string) {
  const unstableRawData = useRouteLoaderData(routeId) as SerializeFrom<T>;

  return unstableRawData;
}
```

So in that example, stableData contains the correct types. `stuff` is what I expect it to be and TS will rightly complain about using stuff that doesn't exist.

In order to cut down on the boilerplate, I ended up doing this, which works, but `rootData` is of type `any`. I don't know what I expected, as I wrote `U = any`.

I want `U` to be whatever shape object the unserializer function returns. I just don't know how to do that.

```
// routes/somechildroute.tsx

// rootData is `any`
const [rootData, updateRootData] = useTypedRouteLoaderData<typeof rootLoader>(
  'root',
  ((x) => { // x is correctly typed
    return {
      ...x,
      user: x.user ? unserialize<User>(x.user) : null,
    };
  })
);

// hooks/useTypedRouteLoaderData.ts
import { useRouteLoaderData } from '@remix-run/react';
import { SerializeFrom } from '@remix-run/node';
import { useCallback, useState } from 'react';

export type Serialized<T = any> = SerializeFrom<T>;
export type UnserializerFn<T = any, U = any> = (data: Serialized<T>) => U;
export function useTypedRouteLoaderData<T = any, U = any>(
  routeId: string,
  unserializer: UnserializerFn<T, U>
) {
  // https://github.com/remix-run/remix/blob/a20ae7fb0727212ac52bdc687513c61851ac4014/packages/remix-react/components.tsx#L1000
  const unstableRawData = useRouteLoaderData(routeId) as SerializeFrom<T>;

  if (!unstableRawData) {
    if (routeId !== 'root' || !routeId.startsWith('routes')) {
      throw new Error(
        `Invalid routeId ${routeId}: it should be "root" or start with "routes".`
      );
    }

    throw new Error(
      `Could not find loader data for ${routeId}. Ensure that the id is correct, see useMatches().`
    );
  }

  const [data, setData] = useState(unserializer(unstableRawData));

  // This just updates it to the latest data from the loader.
  const updateData = useCallback(() => {
    setData(unserializer(unstableRawData));
  }, [unstableRawData]);

  return [data, updateData, unstableRawData];
}
```

Here's a reproduction: https://stackblitz.com/edit/remix-run-remix-62mwl8?file=app%2Froutes%2F_index.tsx,app%2Froot.tsx

Comment: The reason I'm storing the loader data in `useState` is that otherwise the data disappears before my transitions complete which causes errors. The errors can be tl;dr'd into: Can't destructure `undefined`.

Comment: Have you looked at my package `remix-typedjson`? Not only does it let you keep the original TypeScript types in `useLoader`, etc., but it also ensures that native types like Date and BigInt will be converted back to the correct type after being serialized across the network.

Comment: @Kiliman I've actually used it in a previous project. Back then it didn't work in conjuction with namedAction from remix-utils IIRC, which is what we're also using in this project.

Comment: Just a note. `useRouteLoaderData` has `undefined` in its union for a good reason. If you used the hook in a child component that doesn't load (match) the specified route in its parents, then obviously the hook returns `undefined`